# How to get positon of all words from array depends of includes

Tags: javascript

I have the Array below and I want to get position of all three values when I type "ca" so it will return me 1,2,3

```js
const withoutAccent = ["xyz", "can", "cant", "cannot"]
let test = withoutAccent.indexOf(withoutAccent.includes("ca"));
console.log(test)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please have a look at [ask] and ho to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `Array.prototype.map` to map to the index of the array if the search query is matched else it will map to `null`.

The next `Array.prototype.filter` is applied to filter out the `null` from the array for unmatched strings, which is then finally joined to a string using `Array.prototype.join()`:

```js
let letters = ["xyz", "can", "cant", "cannot"];
function getIndices(letters, query){
  return letters.map((letter, idx) => letter.includes(query) ? idx :  null )
                      .filter(e => e !== null )
                      .join(", ");
}
console.log(getIndices(letters, "ca"));

letters = ["xyz", "xy", "cant", "cannot"];
console.log(getIndices(letters, "xy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`

- Loop through array
- Check if str is present in current element or not
- If present add the current index to final output, else don't

```js
let arr = ["xyz", "can", "cant", "cannot"]

let test = (str) => {
  return arr.reduce((op, inp, i) => {
    if (inp.includes(str)) {
      op.push(i)
    }
    return op
  }, [])
}

console.log(test('ca'))
```

***On side note:-***  In case you want to achieve case insensitivity

```
inp.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map to the index using `undefined` as a placeholder for the entries you don't want, then filter them out:

```
const result = test.map((entry, index) => entry.includes("ca") && index)
                   .filter(x => x !== false);
```

The `&&` means that the intermediate array's entries will either be numbers (indexes) or `false` (for the ones we don't want); then we filter out the ones that are `false`. It works because `&&` is curiously-powerful: It evaluates its first operand and, if that's *falsy*, results in that value; otherwise it evaluates its right-hand operand and results in *that* value. So if `includes` returns `false`, the `&&` result is `false`. Otherwise, it's the `index` value.

Live Example:

```js
const test = ["xyz", "can", "cant", "cannot"];
const result = test.map((entry, index) => entry.includes("ca") && index)
                   .filter(x => x !== false);
console.log(result);
```

That makes two passes through the array.

Or use a simple loop:

```
const result = [];
for (const [index, entry] of test.entries()) {
    if (entry.includes("ca")) {
        result.push(index);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const test = ["xyz", "can", "cant", "cannot"];
const result = [];
for (const [index, entry] of test.entries()) {
    if (entry.includes("ca")) {
        result.push(index);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

---

Since your question uses ES2015+ features (`String.prototype.includes`), the examples above use ES2015+ features (`const`, arrow funtions, `Array.prototype.entries`, `for-of`...). You can do this in ES5 and earlier too, though, if you need to:

```
var result = test.map(function(entry, index) {
        return entry.indexOf("ca") !== -1 && index;
    })
    .filter(function(x) {
        return x !== false;
    });
```

and

```
var result = [];
test.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    if (entry.indexOf("ca") !== -1) {
        result.push(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Interested why you would not do `.filter(x => x);`? Or even `.filter(Boolean)`?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - If the first entry contains `"ca"`, that would remove it, as that would be index `0`. So one needs a different test. If there were a builtin `isNotNaN` function, I'd've used `NaN` and then `.filter(isNotNaN)`. :-D

Comment: @DarrenSweeney because lately i would need this numbers to compare with another array.

Comment: @mckvak - No, he's asking why I don't filter out the `undefined` entries that way. (The answer is: Because it would also filter out index `0`.)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - Your `&&` use is a good idea, though. I'll make the answer a CW and fold it in. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Today I was taught, forgot zero was falsy!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - And I forgot to use `&&` (I *knew* something seemed unnecessarily unwieldy above), thanks. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used `startsWith()` as OP said `when I type "ca"...` which to me sounds like trying to achieve some kind of autocomplete possibly - enjoyed this, thank you!!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Im trying to get data from array with accent. :] When user typing without.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `includes`.

```js
const withoutAccent = ['xyz', 'can', 'cant', 'cannot'];
const test = withoutAccent.reduce((acc, val, index) => val.includes('ca') ? [...acc, index] : acc,[]);
console.log(test);
```